# Split vertical studs need replacement or reinforcement

Tags: repair, wood, roof, studs

About a dozen of the short, vertical studs that support my roof rafters are split along as can be seen in the picture. There seems to be some minor horizontal displacement as well.

[image]

Obviously they need to be reinforced or replaced, but I'm not sure what kind of professional could help with this, or if this is something that I can do myself with the proper tools.

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Interesting construction; where is it? Are these supports from a soft low strength wood species? There must be some forceful clamps which could force the parts back together or maybe they could be pulled together with 5/8 " bolts, with large washers under the bolt heads and the nuts. Then put joining plates across the cracks.

Comment: This is in Berkeley, CA. That's an interesting approach that I hadn't considered, thanks! In your opinion, is this something that warrants calling a structural engineer?

Comment: Since you are in an earthquake zone (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayward_Fault_Zone) you should make inquiries about structural engineers in Berkeley who specialize in the analysis of old construction like this. Get an inspection and report from a competent one. This is not an amateur job. What street is this house on?

Comment: I started not far from that area in Sonoma county and saw several old homes with this very tight grain wood that had split. We used straps and Pico nails to pull the boards back together. I would not replace the boards because today's 2x4's only have to have 6 growth rings (4 per inch) to pass those boards probably have 20+ and are clear. We found the root cause was settling / shifting of the walls causing the lateral forces that cracked the studs so investigation into the footings may be needed also. Make sure to use the shorter heavier pico nails not standard nails if you do it this way.

Comment: Luckily we're not in liquefaction terrain, but yes, that's the main concern. I'll look for a contractor and go from there.

Comment: My best guess at the reason is that the previous owner recently added a roof layer, which added weight and probably caused significant vibration during the work.

Comment: Ed Beal, how would you pull the boards back together before securing with the straps and nails? Do you need some sort of progessive clamp or can it be done by nailing at an angle? How many straps would be needed and where would they be placed?